# How to use deprecated methods in older api

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, deprecated, android-contentresolver, android-browser

I have the below code to get the browser history. I know `BookmarkColumns` was deprecated from android M. I want to run this code only if the end device is API<=Lollipop. This method is working good if I change my compiledSDKVersion to 21. But I want my compiledsdkversion to the latest(27). Is it possible to use these methods instead of changing the sdkversion?

I have tried the below, but no luck,

1. `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")`
2. `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {`
3. `@TargetApi(21)`

And also I don't know why its showing as **cannot resolve** `BookmarkColumns` instead of **deprecated**.

```
String[] proj = new String[] { Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE, Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL };
String sel = Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK + " = 0"; // 0 = history, 1 = bookmark
Cursor mCur = getContentResolver().query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, proj, sel, null, null);
mCur.moveToFirst();
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
String title = "";
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
String url = "";
if (mCur.moveToFirst() && mCur.getCount() > 0) {
    boolean cont = true;
    while (mCur.isAfterLast() == false && cont) {
        title = mCur.getString(mCur.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE));
        url = mCur.getString(mCur.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL));
        // Do something with title and url
        mCur.moveToNext();
    }
}
```

Comment: BookmarkColumns was dropped in API 23. So if you keep your target sdk version >=23 that means that you are developing apps which are supported on 23. So you can't use BookmarkColumns directly. However, workaround would be to use reflection

Comment: I am not aware of reflection. Please provide any link or info for more details on reflection?

Comment: `If your app targets Android 6.0 (API level 23) or higher, don't access bookmarks from the global provider or use the bookmark permissions. Instead, your app should store bookmarks data internally.` [source](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes#behavior-bookmark-browser). So apparently you should change the way your app behaves